# MongoDB Replication set + Sharding, after the stop insert data, the count of collection in a database keeps changing, why is this?

Tags: mongodb, count, sharding

MongoDB Replication set +  Sharding, after I stop inserting data, the count of collection in a database keeps changing, why is this?

Comment: Hi, please post a working example of the code you tried, clearly stating where exact place where you are facing the problem. Please see : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

The count keeps on changing because of [shard balancing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-balancer-administration/). When the chunk size in a shard reaches the threshold, the balancer sends a [`moveChunk`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/moveChunk/#dbcmd.moveChunk) command to the source shard.

The steps involved as quoted from the documentation.

> 1. The balancer process sends the moveChunk command to the source shard.
> 2. The source starts the move with an internal moveChunk command. During the migration process, operations to the chunk route to the source shard. The source shard is responsible for incoming write operations for the chunk.
> 3. The destination shard builds any indexes required by the source that do not exist on the destination.
> 4. The destination shard begins requesting documents in the chunk and starts receiving copies of the data. See also Chunk Migration and Replication.
> 5. After receiving the final document in the chunk, the destination shard starts a synchronization process to ensure that it has the changes to the migrated documents that occurred during the migration.
> 6. When fully synchronized, the source shard connects to the config database and updates the cluster metadata with the new location for the chunk.
> 7. After the source shard completes the update of the metadata, and once there are no open cursors on the chunk, the source shard deletes its copy of the documents.

As you can see, data is duplicated in two shards when migration is going on. Hence if the shard balancing is in the state between 1 -7, the count of documents would keep on changing. It's only after step 7 has completely finished, the correct count will be provided.